# Extract "Table1" after selection button using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html-table, beautifulsoup, multipleselection

I tried to download the table in "https://www.bsgroup.com.hk/BrightSmart/MarginRatio/StockMarginRatioEnquiry.aspx?Lang=eng" after selecting the "HK Stock" and "Show All" button. I checked the Chrome/Inspect/Network function. There are no request send to server for new data. Therefore, I suspect the data is in the original page. I checked it appears in "Table1" after pressing the "Show All" button. I tried the following codes, but nothing comes out, please advise:

```
url="https://www.bsgroup.com.hk/BrightSmart/MarginRatio/StockMarginRatioEnquiry.aspx?Lang=eng"
result = requests.get(url)
result.raise_for_status()
result.encoding = "utf-8"

src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll("Table1")
output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

print(output_rows)
```

Comment: https://www.bsgroup.com.hk/BrightSmart/MarginRatio/StockMarginRatioEnquiry.aspx?Lang=eng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For obtaining the data, you have to make `POST` request with correct parameters.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bsgroup.com.hk/BrightSmart/MarginRatio/StockMarginRatioEnquiry.aspx?Lang=eng'

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

    data = {i['name']: i['value'] if 'value' in i.attrs else '' for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    del data['StockMarginRatioGrid$btnFind']
    data['StockMarginRatioGrid$txtExchange'] = 'HKEX'

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=data).text, 'html.parser')

    for tr in soup.select('#StockMarginRatioGrid_gridResult tr'):
        print(''.join('{:^21}'.format(td.text) for td in tr.select('td')))
```

Prints:

```
 Stock Code              Name          Stock Margin Ratio      Deposit Ratio                              Stock Code              Name          Stock Margin Ratio      Deposit Ratio    
      1               CKHHOLDINGS              85%                  15%                                        2               CLPHOLDINGS              85%                  15%         
      3               HK&CHINAGAS              85%                  15%                                        4              WHARFHOLDINGS             82%                  18%         
      5              HSBCHOLDINGS              85%                  15%                                        6               POWERASSETS              85%                  15%         
      8                  PCCW                  75%                  25%                                       10              HANGLUNGGROUP             75%                  25%         
     11              HANGSENGBANK              85%                  15%                                       12              HENDERSONLAND             85%                  15%         
     14                HYSANDEV                75%                  25%                                       16                 SHKPPT                 85%                  15%         
     17               NEWWORLDDEV              85%                  15%                                       18              ORIENTALPRESS             20%                  80%         
     19              SWIREPACIFICA             85%                  15%                                       20                WHEELOCK                82%                  18%         
     23               BANKOFEASIA              75%                  25%                                       25             CHEVALIERINT'L             40%                  60%         

... and so on.
```

---

EDIT: For writing to CSV file you can use this example:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bsgroup.com.hk/BrightSmart/MarginRatio/StockMarginRatioEnquiry.aspx?Lang=eng'

with requests.session() as s, open('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

    data = {i['name']: i['value'] if 'value' in i.attrs else '' for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    del data['StockMarginRatioGrid$btnFind']
    data['StockMarginRatioGrid$txtExchange'] = 'HKEX'

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=data).text, 'html.parser')

    for tr in soup.select('#StockMarginRatioGrid_gridResult tr'):
        writer.writerow([td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td')])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Base on the output, how to export the output to excel? I tried: df = pd.DataFrame(''.join('{:^21}'.format(td.text) for td in tr.select('td')))
df.to_excel("test.xlsx").

Comment: @ArthurLaw Unfortunately, I don't have `pandas` installed, so I cannot help you with that. But look around the site, there's surely tons of info how to save dataframe to excel. I would however suggest to use `csv` module and export data as simple `csv` - Excel will open it for sure.

Comment: Thanks. CSV will be great. And, I tried the following codes,  row with many commas is exported :        with open('BSM.txt','a',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
                writer=csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(''.join('{:^21}'.format(td.text) for td in tr.select('td'))) " , , , , ,S,t,o,c,k, ,C,o,d,e, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,N,a,m,e, , , , , , , , , , ,S,t,o,c,k, ,M,a,r,g,i,n, ,R,a,t,i,o, , , , , , ,D,e,p,o,s,i,t, ,R,a,t,i,o, , , , .."